# How to reference parent modules in Node.js

Tags: node.js, require, node-modules

I have a few files, requiring each other recursively.

`routes.js` requires `api.js`.
`api.js` requires `upload.js`, `pixels.js`, etc.

From `upload.js` or `pixels.js` I want to use fn's in `api.js`.

Currently I'm requring like so, but it doesn't work:

```
// routes.js
var api = require('./api');
api.upload.image(args); // a fn run from routes.js
```

.

```
// api.js
module.exports = {
    upload : require('./upload')
}
```

.

```
// pixels.js
module.exports = {
    get : function (args) {
          console.log(args);
    }
}
```

.

```
// upload.js
var api = module.parent.exports;   // <= tricky part
module.exports = {
    image : function (args) {
          api.pixels.get(args); // <= api is undefined
    }
}
```

The `module.parent.exports` are empty in the sub-modules, and I can't figure out how to `require` them properly.

How should I `require` to get this functionality?

Comment: why is there `;` in api.js on this line `upload : require('./upload');`

Comment: Node supports cyclical requires rather nicely by returning from require an incomplete module that is later filled in. See http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: @DanD. Thanks, makes sense. Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: seems like you need to explicitly export your api.js's `exports` object somehow

Comment: on second thought -- what happens when you just do this?: `var api = module.parent;`  -- that is, leave off the `exports` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is old, but I'll still try to answer.

### Code sequence

Code execution in JS does not happen for all modules instantly. Instead it occurs in a strict sequence. If one thinks about this while looking at where children modules are required and invoked, then the current result makes sense. Though OP's examples do not show explicitly where children modules are required, I guess this happens in the very beginning of the parent module, like so:

```
// api.js
const pixels = require('./pixels.js');
const upload = require('./upload.js');
module.exports = {
  pixels: pixels,
}
```

Indeed when you require **upload.js** (3rd line) the **api.js** knows nothing yet about its future exports (declared below).

### Working example

Based on this understanding let's have a look at a slightly modified code:

```
// api.js
const pixels = require('./pixels.js');
module.exports = {
  pixels: pixels,
}
const upload = require('./upload.js');
let res = upload.image("test values");
console.log(res);
```

---

```
// pixels.js    
function get (args) {
  return "The result of processing " + args;
}
module.exports = {
  get: get
};
```

---

```
// upload.js    
const api = module.parent.exports;

module.exports = {
  image: function (args) {
      return api.pixels.get(args);
  }
}
```

Now when you have your *parent module exports* prepared before invoking **upload** it's not *undefined* within the **image** function anymore.

And if you run **api.js** you'll get:

> The result of processing test values

### Notes

1. Things may become more complicated if referencing parents from multiple modules and/or bidirectionally. I'd say this is a pretty clear sign of bad project's structure and it should be refactored and probably simplified (to have less child to parent references).
2. **module.parent** may become *de facto* deprecated as it was already [discussed and announced to happen](https://github.com/nodejs/node/releases/tag/v14.6.0).